# Can you make a CORS Google API request without OAuth?

Tags: google-api, cors, google-places-api

I would like to make a Google API request from the client instead of the server, in order to save time and load on the server. [This page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) explains using OAuth for CORS, when you want to access a user's private data. I don't want a user's Google data, and don't want users authenticating to their Google account.

The fact that I can get a browser API key makes me think that this is possible, but when I do this:

```
$.get 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?',
  key: browser_key
  location: "#{lat},#{lon}"
  radius: '300'
  sensor: true
```

I get "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Have you tried the Maps JS client: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the JS client works. I gave an HTML node to the PlacesService constructor instead of a map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places